# Best way to splice 2 keys from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Object:

```
var obj = { "2014": {}, "2013": {}, "2012": {}, "description": null, "image": null },
    objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
//objKeys contains [ "2014", "2013", "2012", "description", "image" ]
```

I would like to remove the "description" and "image" from the objKeys array in one go if they exists there.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter them out like this:

```
objKeys = objKeys.filter(function(x){ return !/[a-z]/gi.test(x)});
```

The above uses the fact that other keys are numbers. If you want only `description` and `image`, then put them in an array and do this:

```
var removeKeys = ["description","image"];
objKeys = objKeys.filter(function(x){ return !new RegExp(removeKeys.join("|")).test(x)});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are the keys you wish to keep always numeric?  I'm assuming they're "years"...

```js
objKeys.filter(Number); // ["2012", "2013", "2014"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter them directly using regex.

```
objKeys = objKeys.filter(function(k){ return !/(description|image)/gi.test(k)});
```

Answer (score 1):

A small modification to @hutchbat's answer, why two iterations over keys?

Object.keys is one and filter is another. Here is my code

```
var objKeys = [];
for(var i in obj) if(!/(description|image)/gi.test(i)) objKeys.push(i);
```

So it iterates one times and collects required.